# Angular - Add target to router navigate

Tags: angular, angular4-router

What I want to do is to open the target of router navigate in another tab or in a popup.
My instruction is this:

```
private router: Router;
this.router.navigate(['/page', id]);
```

In routing I have:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'page', loadChildren: './page/page.module#PageModule' }
    ]
}
];
```

I would like to open this link in another tab or in popup window.
What can I do?

---

this is the code of page.ts

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-etichetta',
 templateUrl: './page.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
 animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {


 constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public appService: AppService) {
 }


 ngOnInit() {

 }
}
```

and this is the html:

```
<div [@routerTransition]>
  <br>
  <div class="row">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28):

To redirect manually you should first create an URL where to redirect using `createUrlTree` method, and then redirect.

```ts
const url = this.router.createUrlTree(['/page', id])
window.open(url.toString(), '_blank')
```

---

Declarative navigation should work.

```html
<a target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/page', id]">
  Link
</a>
```

Comment: thanks but I don't have a a element, I have to do this in .ts

Answer (score 4):

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class YourComponent {

   constructor(private router: Router){}

   openNewTab (){
           const host: string =  location.origin;
           const url: string = host + '/#/' + String(this.router.createUrlTree(['/main/product'], { queryParams: { key: encryptData } }));
           window.open(url, '_blank');

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't support navigating to a new tab , you can use window.open to do this

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried this and the link opens on a new tab correctly (localhost/page) but after 1 sec it redirect to localhost

Comment: there should be a redirect logic in your ts, check for it

Comment: @Martina I had the same issue with redirecting. Turns out I had the route slightly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in Angular component HTML file

`<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" routerLink="/create-playlist" > Create Playlist </a>`

Answer (score 1):

The router doesn't have an option to open the link in a new tab. That said, there is a workaround – you can use `target="_blank"` of a hidden link in your template, reference it and click it:

```
<a #link
  style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" 
  [routerLink]="['/page', id]"
  target="_blank"
  queryParamsHandling="merge"
></a>

@ViewChild('link', { static: false }) private link: ElementRef;

this.link.nativeElement.click();
```